# Lightswitch HTML Client Default Insert Screen Dimmed (All Controls Disabled)

Tags: html, client, screen, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am creating a simple lightswitch application to collect some form data from user. I am using the latest **HTML client** release for VS 2012. The problems is with the insert screen, If I create it by default linking it to the simple server data object, it renders dimmed when viewed in browser. All controls are disabled including the save button. If I create a List All screen and from there fire the insert screen, it shows fine with all controls enabled. The idea is that I want the insert screen to be home screen for the application. I will just collect some info from user and then redirect him somewhere else. All the demos/samples out there do not include the insert screen as home screen

BTW, this pattern does not happen with the silverlight client

Regards
Yousry

Comment: Tried anything? Show that code. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: There is no custom code at all. Pure lightswitch [create a new table then add an insert screen for the table and make it home screen]

Comment: This may help: Saving Data In The Visual Studio LightSwitch HTML Client (Including Automatic Saves) http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/173/Saving-Data-In-The-Visual-Studio-LightSwitch-HTML-Client-Including-Automatic-Saves.aspx

Comment: @Yousry, did you get an answer? can you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

The AddEditScreen receives a parameter that is the entity is going to add or edit, in the case of a new record it needs myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.YourEntities.addNew() in that property.
YourEntities is the name of your entity in plural.
ApplicationData changes if you are using an external database instead of the intrinsic one.

When you call the screen in the startup with "Set as home screen" it will run but it can't receive the record it needs to operate on, so it shows the screen as disabled.

Alas I don't know where you need to write the code to make it work. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In default.html you can add something like this.

```
msls._run().then(
                function () {
                    var myapp = msls.application;
                    myapp.showScreen("AddDec", null, {
                        beforeShown: function (addEditScreen) {                            
                            var newDC = new myapp.Dec();
                            addEditScreen.Dec = newDC;
                        },
                        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction) {

                        }
                    });

                },
                function failure(error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            );
```

It works for me.